# How to take a copy of nullable object in TypeScript to keep type?

Tags: typescript

Is it any operator, or generic solution to take copy of nullable object, and the result should be the same nullable type?

Like here, but `...` spread operator will not retain type.

```js
const [startPaymentIn, setStartPaymentIn] = useState<
  StartPaymentIn | undefined
>(undefined);

let startPaymentIn2: StartPaymentIn | undefined = {
  ...startPaymentIn,
};
```

Comment: You could write `startPaymentIn && {...startPaymentIn}`, for example. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can retain the type...

```
startPaymentIn && {...startPaymentIn}
```